# Сменить кодировку текста взятого из файла с помощью file_get_contents()

Tags: php, utf-8

Доброго времени! У меня такой вопрос - есть у меня файл txt с рандомным текстом - я загружаю его на сервер и с помощью функции file_get_contents() вытаскиваю в переменную содержимое этого файла, далее к примеру я захочу вывести содержимое на экран или занести с БД без разницы, - если у меня сайт (БД) работает с кодировкой utf-8 и в документе utf-8 то все проходит корректно, если скажем txt был создан как водится в WINDOWS-1251 то естественно текст получается кракозябрами, есть ли способ изменить кодировку символов в переменной php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать двумя способами:

`$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'utf-8', 'cp1251');`

`$text = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8', $text);`

Документация: [iconv()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php), [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-convert-encoding.php).

Comment: а если не известна исходная кодировка то ее можно определить функцией mb_detect_encoding() ? и подставить в iconv ?

Comment: Это распространённый метод, но я видел жалобы на то, что эта функция не всегда корректно работает. Сам, правда, я с проблемами не сталкивался.

Comment: сам сейчас эксперементирую и вижу что жалобы оправданны)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте данную [функцию](https://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#85008):

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn)
{
    $content = file_get_contents($fn);
    return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
}
```

Comment: я тоже подумал об mb_detect_encoding() но все равно что то эта функция не правильно определяет\ если грузить в ASCII то выдает что то вроде такого "âûà ôûâàôû àôûâ àôûâ àôûâà" думаю может задать уже готовый массив возможных кодировок за рание типа как $ary[] = "ASCII";
$ary[] = "JIS";
$ary[] = "EUC-JP";
mb_detect_encoding($str, $ary);